# ClickAwayListener is disabling onClick in a nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm having an issue where the clickAwayListener material-ui component is disabling the onClick event in one of my buttons on a nested component.

Everything works properly when I remove the ClickAwayListener, but when it is there it disables onClick.

Currently the handle delete function deletes a specified area on the page.

it should be noted that the DeleteArea component is a dialog that is located within a dialog. It asks the user if they are sure they want to delete the specified area.

Also handleClear is altering the state and I'm thinking that has something to do with it, since i tried changing it to a console log and it works properly when handleClear is not called.

```
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClear}>
  <CustomForm />
</ClickAwayListener>


in CustomForm:
<...>
  <DeleteArea onClick={handleDelete()}>
</...>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the user be able to click away but to also have the delete button work properly.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `onClick={handleDelete}` not `onClick={handleDelete()}`?

Comment: Yes you are correct, i fixed that but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same thing. It appears that the `onClickAway` handler is called before the `onClick` handlers of its children.

In my case clicking away changes the state so that some of its children won't be rendered. The child with the broken onClick was one of those and was rendered in a react portal so `onClickAway` was being triggered when clicking on this child. This meant that the child would no longer be rendered by the time it would have triggered its `onClick` handler.

I don't love this workaround, but wrapping the `onClickAway` handler in a `setTimeout` (0ms) fixed the issue for me.

An example:

```
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => setTimeout(onDelete)}>
...
```

I know this question is a little old and I'm not sure if it fixes your problem but I figured it might help someone that runs into this issue.